# How to find a record that wasn't saved yet in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

Say I have a record called `Post` that has many comments.
Now I run the following code:

```
p = Post.new
p.comments.build(:title => 'great')
```

I would now like to locate that comment by its title.
If the record was saved, I could do something like

```
p.comments.find_by_title('great')
```

But since it isn't saved yet, that's going to return nil (because it actually runs an SQL query)
Is there a way to locate this record before it's saved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
great_comment = p.comments.detect{|c| c.title == 'great'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
comment = p.comments.build(:title => "great")
```

Comment: you're actually right, but I'd like to fetch it later, without having to set a variable for it (I'm reading it from another place before the record is saved). I should have specified that.

Comment: In that case, you simply want to use a different type of variable storage. Try `session[:comment]`, `@comment`, or `@@comment`, depending on your situation (be careful with that last one).

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
new_comment = p.comments.build(:title => 'great')
```

and `new_comment` will be the newly added comment.

Or, you could do something like:

```
new_comments = p.comments.select{|x| x.new_record?}
```

which would give you an array with all the unsaved comments.

Comment: your second solution is close to what I want, but I'm looking for a specific record. I suppose I could do `p.comments.select{|x| x.new_record? && x.title == 'great' }`, but isn't that a waste of resources?

Comment: You are just iterating over the `comments` in memory. I was also assuming that at a given moment, only 1 record will be a new, unsaved, record. But if that is not the case, indeed add the extra condition. Ideally, indeed, you would keep the new comment inside a variable where you can access it straightaway.